# VS 2015 Web Site Solution Office Interop Word

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-word, office-interop

I have this Web Site solution in VS 2015, it is a migrated solution from VS2005 without VS2015 web Site Solution folder Structure,

Solution is working perfectly fine, so I don't find the reason to migrate it.

I have used Microsoft.office.interop.word.dll to read Word docs and do some processing.

It is working perfectly fine in local machine.

Now I deployed it to Server Windows 2012 IIS 7.

It is giving trouble with the dll missing error.

I have used Primary Interop Assemblies.

I have installed MS office 2013 on to server.

It is giving regdb error. I have made changes to dcomcnfg as per some suggestion of similar problems.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Can some body throw some light to show me a solution for this problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago Microsoft changed aproach for this Interop Libraries. Instead of adding a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies as available in the Add Reference dialog, .NET Framework tab, you should use COM tab.You should pick something like "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library". You should remove Yours interop reference and add new one. (from COM tab).

Comment: Thx for response Whencesoever, I used Microsoft 15 object library which installed interp.microsoft.office.core.dll. It is working as similar as Microsoft.office.interop.word.dll. It might be an alternative for interop but not resolving the COM Class error. Wondering if I Should remove the MS Office from server?

Comment: Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll is not working for me as It is not showing word document processing code.